# "Alarm clock" message in linux

Tags: c, linux, message, alarm, sigaction

```
struct sigaction act;
memset(&act,0,sizeof act);
sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
alarm(any_seconds);
```

My alarm code in linux.

I met "Alarm clock" message. But I don't want met this message.

How can I do? please help.

Comment: If you do `alarm(0)` you disable the alarm

Comment: What did you expect the sigaction call to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the signal

```
static void alarmHandler(int signo)
{
    (void)signo;
    printf("Another message\n"); // or skip this line
}

...
alarm(any_seconds);
signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
```